# How to modify if condition

Tags: if-statement, nested-if

---

Sorry for being little vague, it's a minor coding related doubt but I'm not sure how to code it as simply as possible.

Following is the if condition:

```
   if (OF_IS_FLAG_SET(pOfHwData, OF_HW_OUTPUT_PORT) ||
         OF_IS_FLAG_SET(pOfHwData, OF_HW_OUTPUT_MULTIPORT)||
         OF_IS_FLAG_SET(pOfHwData, OF_HW_TUNNEL_PORT)||
         OF_IS_FLAG_SET(pOfHwData, OF_HW_OUTPUT_FLOOD)) { /* do something */ }
```

I want to include another `OF_IS_FLAG_SET()` based upon another X condition. Basically,

```
if(X) {
if (OF_IS_FLAG_SET(pOfHwData, OF_HW_OUTPUT_PORT) ||
             OF_IS_FLAG_SET(pOfHwData, OF_HW_OUTPUT_MULTIPORT)||
             OF_IS_FLAG_SET(pOfHwData, OF_HW_TUNNEL_PORT)||
             OF_IS_FLAG_SET(pOfHwData, OF_HW_OUTPUT_FLOOD)||
             OF_IS_FLAG_SET(pOfHwData, NEW_FLAG)) { /* do something */ }}
else {
if (OF_IS_FLAG_SET(pOfHwData, OF_HW_OUTPUT_PORT) ||
             OF_IS_FLAG_SET(pOfHwData, OF_HW_OUTPUT_MULTIPORT)||
             OF_IS_FLAG_SET(pOfHwData, OF_HW_TUNNEL_PORT)||
             OF_IS_FLAG_SET(pOfHwData, OF_HW_OUTPUT_FLOOD)) { /* do something */ }
}
```

But I don't want to re-write the exact same blocks of /* do something */. How do I include the new flag `OF_IS_FLAG_SET(pOfHwData, NEW_FLAG)` based upon if X is true, and not otherwise.

Comment: Move the `if(X)` into the larger `if (OF..)` code block. Then you only need to do `if(X)` and `else`. If `X` depends on `NEW_FLAG`, then just check `if(X) && OF_IS_FLAG_SET(pOfHwData, NEW_FLAG)`.

Comment: if((X && OF_IS_FLAG_SET(/*the set of flags with X*/)) || (OF_IS_FLAG_SET(/*the set of flags without X*/))

Answer (score 1):

```
if (OF_IS_FLAG_SET(pOfHwData, OF_HW_OUTPUT_PORT) ||
         OF_IS_FLAG_SET(pOfHwData, OF_HW_OUTPUT_MULTIPORT)||
         OF_IS_FLAG_SET(pOfHwData, OF_HW_TUNNEL_PORT)||
         OF_IS_FLAG_SET(pOfHwData, OF_HW_OUTPUT_FLOOD))
{ 
    if ( X && OF_IS_FLAG_SET(pOfHwData, NEW_FLAG) )
    {
       /* X is true and all the checks are true, including the additional one depending on X */
    }
    else if (!X)
    {
       /* X is not true but all the checks are true */
    }
    else 
    {
       /* X is true but the additional check has failed */
    }

}
else
{
   /* Some check has failed. */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to merge the common conditions:

```
if (OF_IS_FLAG_SET(pOfHwData, OF_HW_OUTPUT_PORT) ||
    OF_IS_FLAG_SET(pOfHwData, OF_HW_OUTPUT_MULTIPORT)||
    OF_IS_FLAG_SET(pOfHwData, OF_HW_TUNNEL_PORT)||
    OF_IS_FLAG_SET(pOfHwData, OF_HW_OUTPUT_FLOOD) {
  if(X) {
    if (OF_IS_FLAG_SET(pOfHwData, NEW_FLAG)) {
      /* do something */
    }
  } else {
   /* do something */
  }
}
```

this is equivalent to the flow in your question

Answer (score 0):

```
if((X && (isFlagsUp() || OF_IS_FLAG_SET(pOfHwData, NEW_FLAG))) || isFlagsUp()) {
 /* do something */
}

int isFlagsUp() {
  if ((OF_IS_FLAG_SET(pOfHwData, OF_HW_OUTPUT_PORT) ||
       OF_IS_FLAG_SET(pOfHwData, OF_HW_OUTPUT_MULTIPORT)||
       OF_IS_FLAG_SET(pOfHwData, OF_HW_TUNNEL_PORT)||
       OF_IS_FLAG_SET(pOfHwData, OF_HW_OUTPUT_FLOOD)) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers everyone, I didn't imagine producing some more conditions based on `OF_IS_FLAG_SET(pOfHwData, NEW_FLAG)`. Basically I just want `OF_IS_FLAG_SET(pOfHwData, NEW_FLAG)` to be included in the original if condition if X is true, not otherwise.

```
   bool XisTrue = ((getCompatibilityMode()) ? FALSE : TRUE);

   if (OF_IS_FLAG_SET(pOfHwData, OF_HW_OUTPUT_PORT) ||
         OF_IS_FLAG_SET(pOfHwData, OF_HW_OUTPUT_MULTIPORT)||
         OF_IS_FLAG_SET(pOfHwData, OF_HW_TUNNEL_PORT)||
         OF_IS_FLAG_SET(pOfHwData, OF_HW_OUTPUT_FLOOD)||
         (XisTrue && OF_IS_FLAG_SET(pOfHwData, NEW_FLAG)))
```

`getCompatibilityMode()` decides whether X is true. This seems to be fixing the issue.
Please let me know if I missed something or if I'm not clear enough.

Comment: And yes, XisTrue is indeed true if CompatibilityMode is false. Just FYI.